# Blacklist for filters

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, plupload, uploader

Plupload has ability to filter by extension.
In documentation, in the plupload settings:
White extensions list:

```
filters : [
    {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
    {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
]
```

Is it possible to make extensions blacklist, for example:

```
filters : [
    {title : "All files", extensions : "*"},
    {title : "Exclude files", extensions : "!exe"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into plupload sources, it seems that plupload does not allow this, at least for HTML5 uploader.

This seems consistent with the fact that the HTML5 uploader uses the accept attribute. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_select which does not allow black lists.

Though not user-friendly, you could use the FilesAdded event to remove unwanted files as soon as they are added. http://www.plupload.com/example_events.php